# How to always return subquery result?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

I know this question was asked alot, but couldn't figure out if i should use `COALESCE` `ifnull` or something else.

I have the following query :

```
 select (amount-
(select (sum(l.amount_sum)-sum(lr.reward)) as total
from logs l
join logs_rewards lr on l.id = lr.related_log_id
where l.agent_id = '1'))
as balance
from logs_payments
where agent_id = '1'
```

Now the problem is if the `agent_id` doesn't exist in `logs_payments` the query will not return rows, but i want it to do is to return the result anyway but if `amounts` doesn't exist, set it  as 0 for the subquery

Now i've thought about querying a different table and just joining the result like this :

```
select (lp.amount-
(select (sum(l.amount_sum)-sum(lr.reward)) as total
from logs l
join logs_rewards lr on l.id = lr.related_log_id
where l.agent_id = '1'))
as balance
from agents a
join logs_payments lp on lp.agent_id = a.id
where a.id = '1'
```

But that didn't work either. what approach should i take to this problem?

To make it clear i want this query to always return amount-result of subquery, if no amount exist still return result but calculate it as 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well i got it to work using JW's comment about LEFT JOIN and Saharsh's remark about `ifnull` using the following code :

```
select ifnull(sum(lp.amount),0)-
(select (sum(l.amount_sum)-sum(lr.reward)) as total
from logs l
join logs_rewards lr on l.id = lr.related_log_id
where l.agent_id = '1')
as balance
from agents a
left join logs_payments lp on lp.agent_id = a.id
where a.id = '1'
```

Thank you both for your assistance!

Comment: Well i would but you're answer was just as helpfull as JW's, it pointed me to the right direction. you're code doesn't work (even if i fix the syntax errors you've got there) so i didn't accepted it and will accept my own, sorry and thanks again for helping out!

Answer (score 0):

use `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT  a.amount - COALESCE(b.total, 0) as balance
FROM    logs_payments a
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT  agent_id, sum(l.amount_sum) - sum(lr.reward) as total
            FROM    logs l
                    INNER JOIN logs_rewards lr 
                        ON  l.id = lr.related_log_id
            GROUP BY agent_id
        ) b ON a.agent_id = b.agent_id
WHERE   a.agent_id = 1
```

Comment: This still returns nothing, as logs_payments does not contain any record of the desired agent_id

Comment: so you mean that you are searchng for specific `agent_id` but if that id has no record, you want to display zero instead of nothing. right?

Comment: Ya but I got it to work, I forgot about left join. Thank you very much JW!

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT l.agent_id, IFNULL(lp.amount, 0) amt, l.total 
FROM (SELECT l.agent_id, (SUM(l.amount_sum) - SUM(lr.reward)) AS total 
      FROM logs l INNER JOIN logs_rewards lr ON l.id = lr.related_log_id 
      WHERE l.agent_id = '1') AS l 
LEFT jon log_payments lp ON l.agent_id =lp.agent_id 
WHERE l.agent_id = '1'
```